Cannot install or search using pip. ProtocolError: PermissionError(13)
Entering $ pip install 'package name' or $ pip search 'package name' on the terminal always results on an error. I'm on a windows 10 operating system, downloaded python from python.org, python version: 3.12.4, pip version: 24.0.
Searched all over the internet for a solution but nothing worked. pip install works fine on my laptop so nothing's wrong with the network. I remember it working just fine in the past  so it's likely that i changed something on the computer, also i remember messing around with chocolatey before the issue (maybe it's related).
This is the error:
$ pip install pyautogui
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/pyautogui/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/pyautogui/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/pyautogui/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/pyautogui/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))': /simple/pyautogui/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyautogui (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyautogui

When entering this command that i found on the internet which looks something like this:
$curl pypi(...).org | (...)
I got an error related to the file 'firefox.browser'
Those are things I tried:

turning firewall off
running command as administrator
using --user tag
using virtual environment (venv)
un / re install python/pip
adding python to path
checking the 256 character path length limitation setting
entering command $pip install --upgrade pip results on the same
error
$curl https://pypi.org/simple/pyautogui/ command works fine


PyPI doesn't support pip search anymore.

I found the answer at https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1539896/pip-permission-denied. which suggests that i use an older version of Python, I downloaded Python version: 3.8.1 with PIP version: 19.2.3 and everything works fine now.
